# Export PDF using puppeteer, using button in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pdf, puppeteer

i have an ReactJS app. and the app will generate the pdf using puppeteer,

i run this command to genera the pdf

```
npm run generate
```

in my package.json the script is

```
"generate": "npx babel-node scripts/generate-pdf.js"
```

in my generate-pdf.js the code like this

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto("http://localhost:3000/", {
    waitUntil: "networkidle2",
  });
  await page.emulateMediaType("screen");
  await page.pdf({
    path: "./react.pdf",
    printBackground: true,
    format: "a4",
  });
  await browser.close();
})();
```

everything goes normally. successfully generated the pdf.

my problem is, how to make button in React to execute the command for generating the pdf file?

Comment: react lives in your front while pupeteer is executed from your server environment. If you want to execute pupeteer programmably, you need to make a API endpoint to execute your pupeteer script.

Comment: @FrédéricLang can you give an example of how to do this?

Comment: why do you want to execute the pdf file when user clicks the button ? You should generate it a build time

Comment: because, the app that I made requires a pdf for each different user

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
await page.waitForFunction(() => window.buttonClicked)
```

And then in react:

```
<button onClick={() => window.buttonClicked = true}/>
```